# How to return all types except a certain type in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Let's say that there is a column called colours and it can have values red, blue, and green. I want to retrieve all rows except the ones where the colour is green. How to do this in MongoDB?

Comment: You should try yourself and share code with us!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use `$ne` operator in mongoDB
for reference look here : https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-ne-operator-in-mongodb